# Borrowing from German in American English

Tags: english, german

Which words were borrowed from German in American English?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://german.about.com/library/blvoc_gerloan.htm) is a list of the words borrowed from German into English (mind, there are 3 pages there). I leave it up to you to decide if it is British or American English.

Comment: than you very much!